# Using ISNULL in SQL LEFT JOIN to check if the result is null, and if it is, use another value to join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL select with a where clause where i want to check if the result is null, and if it is null I want to use another value in the where clause, but i get 0 rows results, even though i know i should get a row as result.

Heres my (updated) SQL code:

```
DECLARE @LanguageCode NVARCHAR(3);
SET @LanguageCode = 'FR'
SELECT 
wi.WorkItemId,
ds.DisplayString AS Team
FROM dbo.WorkItem AS wi 
LEFT JOIN dbo.DisplayString AS ds ON ds.ElementID = wi.TierId AND ds.LocaleID = ISNULL(@LanguageCode, 'ENU')
```

The code above returns data for "@LanguageCode" when there is data to return, but it does not switch to use 'ENU' when there is no data. Thats the problem!

This is also just a sample since this is part of a larger query with lots of left joins where i need the same functionality against "LocaleID". I'm hoping there would be something easy solution to this like the code above.

To clarify what i want to achieve, if the `c.LocaleID = @LanguageCode` returns null rows i want to use the hardcoded value as in `c.LocaleID = ENU`.

If i don't use the ISNULL function and only use 'ENU' it returns the expected result.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Naming a table `column1` induces a bit of cognitive dissonance.

Comment: Do you have 2GB language code values? If not, I suggest you specify the appropriate max size instead of `nvarchar(MAX)`.

Comment: Its not the real name of the column, but i've changed it for censorship reasons.

Comment: it is not 2GB values, but this SQL snippet is just a part of a larger query and i just wrote max for simplification.

Comment: c.LocaleID = ISNULL(@LanguageCode, 'ENU') 
could be 
c.LocaleID = (@LanguageCode is null OR @LanguageCode = 'ENU')

Comment: i would love to make this one " c.LocaleID = (@LanguageCode is null OR @LanguageCode = 'ENU')" working , but i get "incorrect syntax near 'is'" error.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want one row, either with the specified language code or `'ENU'`.  If so, use filtering and `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) c.*
FROM dbo.column1 c 
WHERE c.rowID = '1234-1234-1234' AND 
      c.LocaleID IN (@LanguageCode, 'ENU')
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN c.LocaleID = @LanguageCode THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Yes, that is what i want, but i only want to return 1 row, if there is data for both language codes. I tried your answer, but i then get both rows returned when there is data for both language codes. Any clue?

Comment: @arkenfar . . . This query *cannot* return two rows because of the `SELECT TOP (1)`.

Comment: But i want to return all results, but when the localeID is NULL it should return the result for localeID = 'ENU'.. See my updated code above which is a lot more similar to the whole query except there is a lot of LEFT JOINS where i need the same check against LocaleID. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this

```
select coalesce((SELECT rowID FROM dbo.column1 where c.rowID = '1234-1234-1234' and LocaleID = @LanguageCode),
                (SELECT rowID FROM dbo.column1 where c.rowID = '1234-1234-1234' and LocaleID = 'ENU'));
```

Comment: I tried this one now, and it returns an error saying "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS"

Comment: Sorry it couldn't use the wildcard.  I changed the selects to return rowID.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name c
WHERE c.LocaleID  = 
      case when (select count(*) 
                 from table_name tn
                 where tn.LocaleID = @LanguageCode) = 0 then
          'ENU'
      else
           @LanguageCode
      end;
```

[Here is the demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=078a02a42c44e78bfb9f034df9b2fb19)

Here is a new demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=624100ee44f89decc4c6383e92d0a016

In the new demo I have added some more code to show how to use it in left join as a part of the join condition and also I have added the code to show how to use it in where clause when joining two tables and I believe it belongs in the where clause...

Comment: I am checking other answers now and I do not understand why Gordon's answer is not working for you ?

Comment: i probably should have mentioned it right away, the reason it is not working, is because my query is just a part of a larger query and the real case for me is to use the ISNULL() function in a left join on several columns. And when using "IN" i will get duplicated result with different languages (this is a query giving back result based on language, and if the returned data is 0 it should return ENU, since it is always data for ENU). I just thought it would simplify things by just writing a sample of what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: So does this solution of mine works ? Can you give us the example of data and make it more complicated because without examples .... nothing can be done no more...

Comment: Hi @arkenfar you did not answered my question: why is my code no good for you ?

Comment: Cus i cant see how i can use this in my left join?

Comment: Thank you @VBoka , this could be a working solution. But how would i go about when i want to start another left join on a different 'DisplayString'. When I start another LEFT JOIN after the one you made i'm getting "Incorrect syntax near 'LEFT'". Any clue?

Comment: Hi @arkenfar please tell me which solution is ok for you? With where clause or with and clause ? Show me the query that is not working for you...

Comment: I tried both of them, and it is working when i only have one LEFT JOIN, but once i add another LEFT JOIN i get the incorrect syntax in 'LEFT'. This is what i tried: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fc9a2e422c00686c7bfe5a3c78291732

Comment: Hi @arkenfar , you can not use where like that, first you put all the join's you need and then you put the where clause. For example: SELECT...FROM ... LEFT JOIN ... LEFT JOIN...LEFT JOIN... WHERE...Look at this example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e18ab14f9fe954e8c11031df273bcddb

Comment: Thanks. I think i should show you the query so you maybe see why i can' get this to work. Could also just be that this is above my SQL skills. You will se that the query has a lot of variables, those are just different GUIDS which i just left out for censorship reasons. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=99dbd122871380d81252983999f3376f